# aws auto scaling based on number of users

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

A question about Auto Scaling setup for Amazon AWS.

How can I create an amazon trigger based on increase in the number of visitors / users to my website ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good guide ( http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ ):

Also take a look at http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/